# Accessing user attributes in Okta's custom email template

Tags: okta

When creating a custom email template for user activation in Okta, I'm able to access a User's login, firstName, and lastName using Okta's Expression Language syntax, i.e. `${user.login}`.

However, there are other user profile attributes such as Title that I'm not able to access using `${user.title}`. Has anyone successfully managed to access user attributes outside of `{login, email, lastName, firstName}`?

According to the official docs here: [Okta Expression Language](https://developer.okta.com/reference/okta_expression_language/#popular-expressions)

> When you create an Okta expression, you can reference any attribute that lives on an Okta user profile or App user profile.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this functionality as well. Looking at [this support ticket](https://support.okta.com/help/answers?id=9062A000000Xa58QAC&feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=xMFA&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&), it seems like Okta only supports several user profile attributes in Email templates:

> currently Okta supports a limited ammount of customizable variables.
>   See the article below for details.
>   https://help.okta.com/en/prev/Content/Topics/Settings/Settings_Email.htm

Further, [looking at their documentation for email templating](https://support.okta.com/help/blogdetail?id=a67F0000000blN1IAI), they only reference four accessible user profile attributes: `login`, `email`, `firstName`, and `lastName`.